# forward price and forward rate of a corporate bond

Tags: forward, forward-curve, corporate-bond

For risk free zero coupon bonds we can derive forward rates from observed the prices of zero coupon bonds. For example if the 1y zero rate is 1% and the 2y zero rate is 2% we can derive that the 1yr forward is 3% (approximately).

Furthermore, the t0 price of the 2y bond is 96%, and if we calculate the 1year forward of that it would be (1.01)*B(0,2) = 97%.

How does the above work in the context of corporate bonds?
If we have a risk free zero curve, and if we have a credit spread curve on top that we can use to price corporate bonds.

Do we have forward credit spreads? What's the interpretation?
I was not able to find a good reference on this topic, any help would be appreciated.